External HDD has error and won’t mount for backup
I’m running Sonoma.  My external HDD has 4 partition (volumes). One of them can’t be repaired by macOS.
However when plugged to old Mac with High Sierra it shows no problem. Is there a known fix for this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Thank you. I can’t open up any files nor can I back up the disk. I must back up before I can reformat and within a minute of mounting the disk it just spews it out.

Why can’t you back up the disk when it’s connected to the old Mac? You say it’s working then.

The old Mac is not mine. I used acquaintance’s to try it out. It’s 2011. Usb2.0. It would take days to copy 3T of data.

Either the drive, the cable, or the USB port is probably malfunctioning. As you have no backups and can't back up now, there is nothing you can do with the drive without risking data loss. If you have, or can borrow, another drive that is known good, you can test it with the same cable to rule out a hardware fault other than in the drive itself. Otherwise, I'm not comfortable making any suggestion except that you take it to a reputable data-recovery service. There are no good options when this kind of thing happens.

Thank you. You’re right. We can’t rule out the cable. It’s suspicious that it works when connected directly to the old Mac as the native USB-A but not with the adapter to usb-c on the new Mac. Thank you for your insight. (As a final note though, it worked fine before updating to OS 10.14.2)

what are the partition types ? APFS,HFS,NTFS ? ..or a mix ?

All 4 partitions are HFS+.
